# Why *Change EventEmitter listeners are emitted two times in Angular (custom two-way data binding property)?

Tags: angular

Here is the way how to create two-way-data-binding in Angular: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html#creating-custom-two-way-data-bindings

For example I created `counter` two-way data binding property in a component. It works. Now I also want to get notifications about changing the property using `counterChange` output of the component.

Here is the code of the component:

```
export class CustomCounterComponent {

  counterValue = 0;
  @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter();

  @Input()
  get counter() {
    return this.counterValue;
  }

  set counter(val) {
    this.counterValue = val;
    this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
  }
}
```

Here is how I use it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <custom-counter [(counter)]="counterValue" (counterChange)="onChange($event)"></custom-counter>
    <p><code>counterValue = {{counterValue}}</code></p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  onChange(value) {
    console.log('onChange!', value)
  }
  counterValue = 5;
}
```

Desired behavior: I expect `onChange` to be called 1 time when value changes.

Specific problem: `onChange` is called two times each time values changes.

Any thoughts why it is called 2 times?

Also, I have full plunkr example: https://plnkr.co/edit/8HGXNhhYQRoLVJeDlqWK?p=preview. Just open console and look there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

After digging little bit further, I've found the real problem.

If you put a breakpoint in `set counter` method and click on `+` button, you'll see it'll trigger twice. That's why, it emits an event twice and `onChange` method gets called twice.

Also, I checked the call stack and see where `set counter` was called from.

First one, as you would suspect is `this.counter++` which is expected.

Take a look at the second one

[image: Source]

When you change `counter`, it triggers a change detection in angular and angular calls

```
.counter = currVal_2
```

which triggers `set counter` again.

So, I moved `this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);` from `set counter` to both inside of `decrement` and `increment` methods.

```
  set counter() {
    return this.counterValue;
  }

  @Input()
  set counter(val) {
    this.counterValue = val;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
    this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
    this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
  }
```

Take a look at [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/bujPRw6DeXJb3v92ykPj?p=preview).

**---------OLD (PARTIALLY WRONG) ANSWER -------------**

Because you are already using two-way binding and binding the method yourself.

`[(counter)]="counterValue"` is sugar syntax for `[counter]="counterValue" (counterChange)="counterValue = $event"`. So, if you want to have custom `counterChange` method, just delete `()` from `[(counter)]="counterValue"`

For more info, [take a look at the docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)

So, change

```
<custom-counter [(counter)]="counterValue" (counterChange)="onChange($event)"></custom-counter>
```

to

```
<custom-counter [counter]="counterValue" (counterChange)="onChange($event)"></custom-counter>
```

**OR**

you can delete `(counterChange)="onChange($event)"` as well.

Try this,

```
<custom-counter [(counter)]="counterValue"></custom-counter>
```

Comment: That makes sense. I can't use just `[(counter)]` since I need to somehow get notification about changes. But `[*]` + `(*Change)` way forces me to sync `*` model in `*Change` handler. Thats not cool.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm afraid that's the tradeoff you have to accept.

Comment: Hm wait. Look another example. How to achieve this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzhhrh With internal ngModel everything works perfectly. How to achieve this?

Comment: I might be wrong in my answer. I simplified your code and it works as you want it. Take a look at this https://plnkr.co/edit/nhLJF0GileOwuKycVSl5?p=preview. I'll see what's wrong with your code

Comment: @SharikovVladislav check it out

Comment: Well, yep. That makes sense too. I almost digged into same. I realized it is something connected to change detection. Ok! You spend a lot of time. Thank you. 

I am not sure your suggested option is good for me, but you answered the question itself. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think a simpler solution would have been to only fire the event when the values has been changed?